# Controlling inheritability of file handles created by C++ std::fstream in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, fstream, child-process, filehandle

In Windows, when creating a process with [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), one can pass `true` as the `bInheritHandles` argument.

```
CreateProcess( , , , , bInheritHandles, , , , )
```

This means that all file handles marked to be inheritable will be, indeed, inherited by the child process.

How can we control whether the underlying file handle created by C++ `std::fstream` class is inheritable or not?

Comment: You can't.  If you plan to inherit, use CreateFile().

Comment: However, at least if using MSVC there is a way to first get a FILE* from a HANDLE and then bind a std::fstream to that FILE*.

Comment: Why bother with all that. Since you have to use the API, use only the API, not both the API and std.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, `fstream` objects are much easier to use. By using operator `<<` and `>>` you have automatic parsing and stringification of variables.

Comment: @Mercalli all std objects are limited in their functionality when compared to API, and are useful only for basic level of processing. In a full-height project, you want more power and this means the API. Besides, you can still use the buffer-level stream functions, then write the buffer to the file using the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C runtime creates inheritable handles by default.

```
ofstream outFile("filename.txt") ;
CreateProcess("program.exe", ..., true, ...) ; //program.exe will inherit the above file handle
```

So, if you want a handle to be inherited, you don't need to do anything.

If you DO NOT want a handle to be inherited, you have to set the handle's `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` flag yourself using WinAPI function `SetHandleInformation`, like this:

```
FILE* filePtr = fopen("filename.txt", "w") ;
SetHandleInformation( (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(_fileno(filePtr)), HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) ;
ofstream outFile(filePtr) ;
```

In the third line, above, the constructor `ofstream(FILE*)` is an extension to the standard that exists in Visual Studio (I don't know about other compilers).

After that constructor, `filePtr` is now owned by `outFile`, so calling `outFile.close()` closes `filePtr` as well. You can completely forget about the `filePtr` variable.

Documentation: [fopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019), [_fileno](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fileno?view=vs-2019), [_get_osfhandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-osfhandle?view=vs-2019), [SetHandleInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-sethandleinformation)

Comment: Alternatively, instead of "black-listing" all handles that shall not be inherited (and possibly missing OS or library handles that are out of your control), you can white-list specifically these handles you *want* to be inherited by [passing a `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` to `CreateProcess`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `fopen` to open the file you can specify the Windows-specific `"N"` mode in the `fopen` parameters to make the handles not inheritable.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("SomeFile.txt", "rwN");
  if (!fp) {
    return -1;
  }

  system("SomeProcess.exe");

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Sources:

https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/WIN03-C.+Understand+HANDLE+inheritance

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019